# file access denied. FIleupload control on subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, subdomain

I have a subdomain. and there is a page on subdomain. and there is a fileupload control on that page.

When I upload a file it gives error like this

```
  access denied to  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomain.com\adimg\autos\...*
```

The above path I got by using `Server.Mappath` method of C#

How can I make my fileupload control function, control which is on page on subdomain

Answer (score 0):

I have provided read and write access to the application pool identity user to the folder where I was uploading images (IIS work). That solved the problem.